# Scroll direction on phone?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

How do I detect scroll direction on phones?
I am currently using

```
$window.on( 'touchmove', onPhone );
```

to call an onPhone function when touch scrolling happens.
But how do I detect if it's scrolling down or up?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Im assuming you only want scroll up and down direction.

```
var lastPoint = null; //global

$(window).on('touchend', function(e){

    var currentPoint = e.originalEvent.changedTouches[0].pageY;

    if(lastPoint != null && lastPoint < currentPoint ){
        //swiped down
        console.log('you scrolled up');

    }else if(lastPoint != null && lastPoint > currentPoint){
        //swiped up
        console.log('you scrolled down');
    }

    lastPoint = currentPoint;
});
```

If you want to detect left right scroll directions can use the same code but change 'pageY' to 'pageX'.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Nice! Thanks~ I've used the lastPoint concept, but I found that applying it on 'touchend' seems to work better.

Comment: no problem. Nice, I've done a similar thing using the Y co-ordinates from touchstart and comparing that value to the Y co-ordinates of touchend :)

Comment: Make sure the `e` event variable is being passed to the function though :)